# How to integrate ALM with Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: hp-quality-center

I want to integrate ALM 11 with my Ruby on Rails application, by using REST API, to fetch test cases and to send results back to the HP ALM.

Can you please help me with some of examples and references (URLs) for the same, If you have some idea about the same work.

Answer (score 0):

There is rather extensive documentation on the REST API in HP ALM Documentation which includes both listing of all the resources exposed and some code samples.

Tip get to this documentation just go to Help -> Documentation Library inside the ALM client.